# How to simulate GaN (Gallium Nitride) Mosfet circuits on Simulink?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, ltspice, simulink, controller, research

I am doing a research on GaN devices and comparision of their performances in DC DC converters as compared to Si devices. The issue that I am facing is that I can't find a way to simulate them on Simulink as I want to design controllers for these circuits as well. Now, I want to know if I can simulate a buck converter which uses a GaNFET on LTspice and also make a controller for that circuit on LTspice by defining the modelled transfer function, else if there is a way to simulate GaNFETs on Simulink as I could not find any such models for Simulink.

Any/all help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you take a look at this yet?  https://github.com/MelisaSarici/GaN-FET/blob/master/BeforeMilestones/An%20Accurate%20Matlab%20Simulink%20Based%20SiC%20MOSFET.pdf

Comment: Looks like [Simulink can accept subcircuits](https://www.mathworks.com/help/sps/ref/subcircuit2ssc.html).  I would try running [the ".lib" file in this ZIP](https://iganpower.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/GPI65015TO_LTSpice_Nov19_v2.zip) and see if the `subcircuit2ssc` function can deal with it.  It's not a very complex subcircuit at all.

Comment: @SteKulov I will check both of these resources, thanks alot!